# Tablet like smart screen without battery

Tags: tablet, displays, cheap

For a home project I'm looking for a device which will only ever show a web page, mounted on a wall.

I could buy a cheap tablet for that, but I don't like the idea of having a device connected to a charger 24/7, when it was designed to only be charged occasionally. Are there any devices out there which are low cost and designed to be connected to power to work?

Other aspects I'm looking for, of varying importance:

- 7-10 inch screen (color required, but high resolution not important)
- Screen can be set up to turn on/off at given times and stay on for hours at a time.
- Can be set up to boot to a web page by default.
- Ideally the page should show, but a user cannot access anything else without authenticating.
- I wouldn't mind a touch screen, but that's not at all important.

Answer (score 1):

I have looked into doing the same thing. The solution I found is a bit more DIY but it has all of the capabilities you are asking and more.

A [Raspberry Pi](https://smile.amazon.com/dp/B07TD42S27/ref=cm_sw_em_r_mt_dp_U_XcjhEbM1KC87V) and [7in Touchscreen](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07YHVFWBM).

Answer (score 0):

How about a portable monitor and a PC stick. Grab any kiosk software and install it on the PC and you're set to go. Don't know how cost sensitive you are but you can probably get monitor and PC stick for well under $200. This would also allow you to migrate to larger display anytime you like since it would work with pretty much any monitor or TV.

UPDATE: there's any number of options, but quick perusal shows a typical configuration: linux compatible Intel PC Stick ($65 https://www.newegg.com/intel-corp-boxstck1a8lfc-compute-stick-stck1a8lfc/p/N82E16883800005), free kiosk software (Porteus), and a Prechen 10.1" portable monitor ($80 on amazon) or any similar cheap monitor.